# Как выполнять команды в буфере "другого" (other) окна

Tags: emacs

Нужно временно, до нажатия клавиши "Ввод", переключаться в особый режим когда все клавиатурные команды в перенаправляются и выполняются в буфере "другого" окна (other-window).

Зачем это нужно. Во время работы со Slime, при наладке какой-то функции приходится постоянно выполнять одну и ту же последовательно действий:

1. Исправить функцию
2. `C-c C-c` - скомпилировать функцию
3. `C-x o` - переключиться в буфер "другого" окна (там запущен REPL)
4. `M-p` - повторить последнее выражение REPL, возможно его изменить
5. `Enter` - выполнить последнее выражение в REPL
6. `C-x o` - вернутся в исходное окно

Так вот, хотелось бы пункты 3 и 6 исключить, чтобы последовательность действий стала такой:

1. Исправить функцию
2. `C-c C-c` - скомпилировать функцию
3. Войти в режим временного управления "другим" окном (там по-прежнему REPL)
4. `M-p` - повторить последнее выражение REPL, возможно его изменить
5. `Enter` - выполнить последнее выражение в REPL и вернуться в исходное окно

Аналогичная проблема возникает при вызове справки по `C-h f`. Текст справки открывается в "другом" окне и перекрывает REPL, а активным остается исходное окно. И получается чтобы закрыть справку нужно делать одно лишнее переключение в "другое" окно, благо после закрытия справки оно все-таки возвращает в исходное.

Comment: Прочитал комментарий в вопросе про установку VS, поражаюсь вашей выдержке )))

Comment: @NickVolynkin У нас же цель поменять представление рунета об общении :) Ну а вообще причиной агрессии часто является страх, а у страха причинами является непонятность или неизвестность. Поэтому для остановки агрессии часто эффективно просто объяснить человеку что к чему.

Comment: отлично. Предлагаю написать раздел справки на эту тему ))

Comment: если что, это не сарказм.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понял, в чем проблема?
Просто на C-c C-c вешаем функцию, которая будет сначала компилировать, а затем переключаться в другой буфер, а на enter функцию, которая будет выполнять выражение и возвращать буфер.

Comment: проблема в том что хочется универсальное решение